# Rotate Right operation on integer data using floating point operations?

Tags: floating-point, integer, bitwise-operators

I'd like to take a value with an unsigned integer representation, and somehow, using floating point operations, perform a rotate right shift bitwise operation.

Take a look at the cleverness used here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
This uses a magic value and some tricks to perform an operation on a floating point number using integer operations.  What I want is the opposite; the hardware I am using is heavily optimized for floating point but performs poorly with integer operations.  The algorithm is sha256, which makes heavy use of the rotate right operation.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches come to mind:

- Take the bits that hold an integer, stuff them into a variable that expects to hold a float with the same number of bits, and operate on those bits as if they're a float. Hope that the hardware has some floating-point operations that operate on those bits the same way as the integer operations that SHA256 uses.
- Stuff your integer into a floating-point variable with more bits (e.g. put an Int32 into a Double, which can hold 53 bits without losing precision), and then implement the rotate-right operation using mathematical operations.

The first option is unlikely to work. If your hardware is based on the IEEE 754 floating-point standard (the most common standard for floating-point representations), then the floats are stored as bitfields; for example, a double has one sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 53 fraction bits. There won't be any operations that shift the sign bit's value over into one of the exponent-bit slots. And then there are the bit patterns that have special meaning and carry that meaning through the entire operation, like NaNs and infinities. So that whole idea is probably a non-starter.

I'm not confident that the second approach would work either; you would need total control over things like rounding behavior, and would want to convince yourself that you've got the right number of bits in your floating-point values, and you would absolutely need a whole lot of tests to convince yourself that it's getting the expected outputs for a whole range of inputs. But here goes.

A rotate-right operation -- say, x ror y -- breaks down thusly. Let b be the number of bits in x. I'm assuming everything is done using unsigned arithmetic, because it makes the logic a lot simpler.

- We start with `x ror y`.
- That can be expressed as a shift right, a shift left, and an OR, as `(x shr y) or (x shl (b - y))`.
- Shr is the same as dividing by a power of two. Shr drops any bits that fall off the lower end, so we can emulate that by using the floor function. So now we have `floor(x / 2^y) or (x shl (b - y))`.
- Shl is the same as multiplying by a power of two. Shl drops any bits that fall off the upper end, which we can emulate by doing the multiplication modulo 2^b. That gives us `floor(x / 2^y) or ((x * 2^(b - y)) mod 2^b)`.
- Since the results of the shl and the shr are disjoint (they affect different bits in the result), the or could just as well be done with addition. So now we have mathematical notation for the whole rotate operation: `floor(x / 2^y) + ((x * 2^(b - y)) mod 2^b)`.

Now just plug in that formula every place SHA256 does a rotate-right operation, and see if it's faster than integer arithmetic. It seems unlikely but not impossible -- adding two floating-point numbers with different exponents would require fast shift operations inside the FP hardware, even if the integer hardware doesn't have fast shifts.